# Let X and Y be two independent random uniform variables on (0,1). Joint density of (3X-Y, 2X-Y)?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random uniform variables on $(0,1)$. I want to find the joint density of $(3X-Y, 2X-Y)$. 
Calling $T = 3X - Y$ and $S = 2X - Y$, for sure T and S are not independent. So I cannot say that the joint density is the product of the two density functions.

I tried calculating the density function of T, by calculating the density function of $3X$ which is just uniform on $(0,3)$ and of $-Y$ which is just uniform on $(-1,0)$. Then I calculated the density function of the sum using convolution. I got the following result:

$$ f_T(t) = -\frac{1}{3}(z \mathbb{1}_{(-1,2)}(z) + (3-z)\mathbb{1}_{(2,3)}(z)) $$
Now, I should calculate also the density function of S and then use the definition of joint density. I am wondering if there is a faster way to get to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformation is linear and full rank, namely $$\begin{bmatrix} T \\ S \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3 & -1 \\ 2 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix},$$ therefore, you know that $(T,S)$ is also uniform on some parallelogram.  You just have to find its area, which is simply the absolute value of the determinant of the transformation, which is $1$.  So the joint density is $1$ on the support of $(T,S)$.

All that is left is to express the support of $(T,S)$ in terms of indicator functions, which is easily handled by computing the inverse of the matrix transformation:

$$\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 2 & -3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} T \\ S \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} T - S \\ 2T - 3S\end{bmatrix},$$ and since we require each of $X, Y \in [0,1]$, it immediately follows that $$0 \le T - S \le 1, \\ 0 \le 2T - 3S \le 1,$$ and the resulting density may be expressed as the product of indicator functions:

$$f_{T,S}(t,s) = \mathbb 1(0 \le t-s \le 1) \mathbb 1(0 \le 2t - 3s \le 1).$$

While you are correct that $T$ and $S$ are not independent, this does not necessarily mean you must calculate their marginal distributions--in fact, this gets you nowhere with respect to the joint density, precisely because they are not independent.  The joint density is not the product of the marginals in such a case.